# How to track ReactNative WebView

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webview

We have an application that is a single page react app.
We recently released a React Native version of the app where we use `Webview` https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview to encapuslate this single page react app!

I want to trigger an action to distinguish between users visiting through the normal react app versus the web view for analytics tracking. I made the assumption that the webview is always going to give exposure to the `window.ReactNativeWebView` api: https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#the-windowreactnativewebviewpostmessage-method-and-onmessage-prop

So I wrote this code injected an event listener on the react webapp:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  // If there ReactNativeWebView API exists then user is in Mobile app
  // https://spin.atomicobject.com/2019/10/28/communicating-react-native-webview/
  if (!!window.ReactNativeWebView) {
    //DO TRACKING EVENT;
  }
});
```

Sadly this does not work.
What's a good way of tracking from the DOM/ React App inside the webview to track if it's in webview or not?

Answer (score 0):

you could use [`injectedJavaScript`](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Guide.md#the-injectedjavascript-prop)

> This is a script that runs immediately after the web page loads for the first time. It only runs once, even if the page is reloaded or navigated away.

for a naive example, you can set a global variable with the `window` object like this -

```
<WebView
  source={{ uri: '...' }}
  injectedJavaScript={'window.isRN = true;true;'}
/>
```

and in your webapp just check for

```js
if(window.isRN){
 // do react-native things
}
```